# Why are my arrays out of context?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following program :

```
bool boolFlag=true;
        uint length;
        Console.WriteLine("Give me the length of array a:");
        if (boolFlag=UInt32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
        {
            int[] a = new int[length];
            Console.WriteLine("Give me {0} int numbers for array a[] :", a.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (boolFlag = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parsing at Index a[{0}] failed.", i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse length.");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Give me the length of array b:");
        if (boolFlag = UInt32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
        {
            int[] b = new int[length];
            Console.WriteLine("Give me {0} int numbers for array b[] :", b.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                if (boolFlag = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parsing at Index b[{0}] failed.", i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse length.");
        }





        if (a.Length==b.Length)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("a and b have equal Length");
        //    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        //    {
        //        if (a[i]==b[i])
        //        {
        //            boolFlag = true;
        //            continue;
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("a[{0}] != b[{0}]", i);
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("The arrays don`t have equal length");
        //}
        Console.ReadLine();
```

When i get to the comparison part i get :
Error   1   The name 'a' does not exist in the current context
Error   2   The name 'b' does not exist in the current context

Why does this happen ?

My 2nd try changed code ...declare arrays out of statements scope :

```
int[] a;
        int[] b;
        bool boolFlag=true;
        uint length;
        Console.WriteLine("Give me the length of array a:");
        if (boolFlag=UInt32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
        {
            a = new int[length];
            Console.WriteLine("Give me {0} int numbers for array a[] :", a.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (boolFlag = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parsing at Index a[{0}] failed.", i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse length.");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Give me the length of array b:");
        if (boolFlag = UInt32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
        {
            b = new int[length];
            Console.WriteLine("Give me {0} int numbers for array b[] :", b.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                if (boolFlag = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parsing at Index b[{0}] failed.", i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse length.");
        }





        if (a.Length==b.Length)
        {
        //    Console.WriteLine("a and b have equal Length");
        //    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        //    {
        //        if (a[i]==b[i])
        //        {
        //            boolFlag = true;
        //            continue;
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("a[{0}] != b[{0}]", i);
        //        }
        //    }
        }
        else
        {
        //    Console.WriteLine("The arrays don`t have equal length");
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Now i get :

Error   1   Use of unassigned local variable 'b'
Error   2   Use of unassigned local variable 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `a` and `b` outside of their scope. Move their declaration to the beginning of your code and assign them to `null`. Note that you might want to consider stopping the execution when the user inputs bad length. Place `return;` after displaying the error message.

Also, consider checking out [this](http://www.codecandle.com/articles/csharp/variables/variable-scope.html) useful article about variable scope.

Comment: I tried that see my changed code I edited the post..now i get a new error which seems to say pretty much the same thing.Check my edit.

Comment: Check my modified answer

Comment: Thank you very much.Although i had already tried before posting out of if scope declaration i never assigned the arrays to null.

Comment: Glad to help :) I modified my answer one last time because your current code breaks on bad inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the a and b arrays outside the ifs, even if you assign values to them inside them. So move int[] a=new int[0]; and int[]b = new int[0]; at the beginning of your code and change your if to if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && a.length == b.length).

Comment: I have already tried that...look at my 2nd try code.Now i get                                 Error   1 : Use of unassigned local variable 'a' and Error 2 : Use of unassigned local variable 'b'.

Comment: see edit. as the error says assign somthing to them so the program knows what to do in all other cases.

Comment: Thank you,This solution works as well, length is uint so if the user gives a negative number the tryParse() will fail anyway.